# iframe.src = "page.html" versus iframe.location.assign("page.html")

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Both of these statements will direct the browser to 'page.html' but when setting the `iframe.src` attribute directly, it actually allows me to query the iframes src attribute in the future.

Using just the location side of things I can reach out and do
    window.top.document.getElementById('page').contentWindow.location.pathname.split('/').pop()

which will give me the page name much like iframe.src would give, but I was curious about the fundamental difference between the two

thanks